# Populate Vue data object, and console log results

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a huge list of data in a Vue component that I would like to dynamically populate. I'm trying to do that by a loop, and a global variable. It looks like below:

```
    var filterItems = document.querySelectorAll('.filter-title');
    var filterItemsTitle = filterItems.innerHTML;
    var arr = [];

    function buildContent() {
      for (var i = 0; i < filterItems.length; i++) {
        arr.push(filterItems[i].innerHTML);
      }
      console.log(arr)
    }

    window.onload = buildContent

    var titleFilter = new Vue({
      // in items its refering to arr built in buildContent
      el: '#filter',
      data: {
         // arr comes from buildContent() - I think...does this work?
         items: arr,
         filters: [
            { label: 'All Titles', value: false },
            { label: 'a', value: 'a' },
            { label: 'b', value: 'b' },
            { label: 'c', value: 'c' },
        ],
        currentFilter: false,
      },
      methods: {
        filterItems: function(e){
          console.log(items)
        }
      }
    });
```

Basically what I want to do is take the `arr` variable which is populated with an array of content in the `buildContent()` loop and reference it in the items data section of my vue component

1. is this possible? Or no?
2. How can I `console.log()` the `items` object? When I try to do it it is undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing filterItems to:

```
filterItems: function(e){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.items))
    }
```

From looking at the code you provided, that should work.

Comment: Just for extend a little bit the @JohnP's answer, the problem in your **filterItems** method is that you don't refer correctly to the items property, in fact you need the `this` as a reference to the calling object (usually as in every oop approaches).